# How is it Possible to order <DIV>s by date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, date, sanity

i ran into a problem when using an ordering function.

```js
var $wrapper = $('#list');

$wrapper.find('.blogboxes').sort(function (a, b) {
    return +b.dataset.date - +a.dataset.date;
})
.appendTo( $wrapper );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">

<div class="blogboxes" data-date="2023. 01. 28."></div>

<div class="blogboxes" data-date="2023. 01. 29."></div>

<div class="blogboxes" data-date="2023. 01. 30."></div>

<div class="blogboxes" data-date="2023. 01. 24."></div>
</div>
```

if i put numbers in the data-date it works fine(desc), but with date it doesn't.
I get my date from a Sanity query in this format:
"2023-01-28T12:10:00.000Z"
which isn't even showing, so i use this:
{new Date(post.publishedAt).toLocaleDateString()}

Can i convert my query output to be orderable by the sort function?

Example in Jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/5e4y9xbj/

Edit:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import "./pagestyles.css"
import sanityClient from "../client.js"
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import $ from "jquery"

const orderBy = () => {
  var $wrapper = $('#list');

  $wrapper.find('.blogboxes').sort(function (a, b) {
      return +b.dataset.date.replaceAll(/\. ?/g, '') - +a.dataset.date.replaceAll(/\. ?/g, '');
  })
  .appendTo( $wrapper );

};

export default function Blog() {
                  const [postData, setPost] = useState(null);
                  useEffect(()=> 
                  {sanityClient.fetch('*[_type =="post"]  {title, publishedAt, slug, extract, mainImage{asset->{_id, url},alt}}'

                                    ).then((data)=> setPost(data))
                                      .catch(console.error);
                  },[]);

window.addEventListener('scroll', orderBy);

  return (
    <main>
  <div className="kontener">   
  <h1>Blog</h1>  
    <div id="list" className="flex-container">
          { postData && postData.map((post, index)=>(
          <div className="blogboxes" key={index} data-date={new Date(post.publishedAt).toLocaleDateString()} >
            <div >
            <div className="contentzoom" >
            <img className="miniblog" src ={post.mainImage.asset.url} 
                 alt ={post.mainImage.alt}   />
              </div>
                  <NavLink className="posztlink" to={"/blog/" + post.slug.current} key ={post.slug.current}>
                    {post.title}
                  </NavLink>
                  <div className="extract">{post.extract}</div>
              </div>
          </div> ))}    
    </div>
  </div>
  </main>
)
}
```

Comment: Use an ISO 8601 date format like `2023-01-28` and use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?retiredLocale=nl) object to compare dates.

Comment: @jabaa `new Date('2023. 01. 28.')` results in an `Invalid Date` value.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier You don't need to convert to `Date`. You can compare the strings. See my answer. `Date` is overkill for this problem.

Comment: @jabaa Ah, I learned something today. Thanks for that. Though I would still recommend using a format that is universal, just for our sanity ;).

Comment: The ordering works with your codes, but i ran into another problem during testing. If i refresh the page or navigate to another and back to this, the ordering resets and wont happen again. So i added an event listener with scroll trigger, and it works with it. Since im a very very beginner i don't know what could be the reason. Any guess?

Comment: Nevermind. I just called it as a component like i supposed to. Huhh. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the strings. Remove the conversion to numbers:

```js
var $wrapper = $('#list');

$wrapper.find('.blogboxes').sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.dataset.date.localeCompare(a.dataset.date);
})
.appendTo( $wrapper );
```

```css
div[data-date] {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: teal;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #023636;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #58BBBB;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 4px auto;
    text-align: center;
}

div[data-date]:before {
    content: attr(data-date);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">

<div class="blogboxes" data-date="2023. 01. 28."></div>

<div class="blogboxes" data-date="2023. 01. 29."></div>

<div class="blogboxes" data-date="2023. 01. 30."></div>

<div class="blogboxes" data-date="2023. 01. 24."></div>
</div>
```

Another approach is to convert the strings to a format that can be converted to numbers:

```js
var $wrapper = $('#list');

$wrapper.find('.blogboxes').sort(function (a, b) {
    return +b.dataset.date.replaceAll(/\. ?/g, '') - +a.dataset.date.replaceAll(/\. ?/g, '');
})
.appendTo( $wrapper );
```

```css
div[data-date] {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: teal;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #023636;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #58BBBB;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 4px auto;
    text-align: center;
}

div[data-date]:before {
    content: attr(data-date);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">

<div class="blogboxes" data-date="2023. 01. 28."></div>

<div class="blogboxes" data-date="2023. 01. 29."></div>

<div class="blogboxes" data-date="2023. 01. 30."></div>

<div class="blogboxes" data-date="2023. 01. 24."></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Javascript Date function for comparison of two dates inside the sort function for descending order.

For that you need to first convert your date to local date format with Javascript function and after that you can sort based on its value.

So now your final code will be :

```
var $wrapper = $('#list');

$wrapper.find('.blogboxes').sort(function (a, b) {
    var dateA = new Date(a.dataset.date);
    var dateB = new Date(b.dataset.date);
    return dateB.getTime() - dateA.getTime();
})
.appendTo( $wrapper );
```

**Result :**
[image]